# SQL JOIN two tables in SELECT into statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can JOIN table "a" to other table in this procedure?

I have two tables and want to join `tbl_ads` and `tbl_state`.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAdPageWise]  
        @PageIndex INT = 1  
       ,@PageSize INT = 3  
       ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
          SET NOCOUNT ON;  

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
                (  
                      ORDER BY [Id] DESC  
                )AS RowNumber  
          ,a.Id  
           ,a.ad_title
           ,a.ad_state
           ,a.ad_city
          ,a.ad_brief  
          ,a.ad_pic    
        INTO #Results  
        FROM [tbl_ads] a 


    END
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly ? and with other tables means and what is the requirement ?

Comment: but when I use this it give an error: `code         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
                (  
                      ORDER BY [Id] DESC  
                )AS RowNumber  
          ,a.Id  
           ,a.ad_title
     ,a.ad_state
     ,a.ad_city
    ,a.ad_brief  
          ,a.ad_pic    
        INTO #Results  
        FROM [tbl_ads] a join tbl_state b ON a.ad_city=b.Id `  ERROR: Ambiguous column name 'Id'.

Comment: put your whole query here so we can give you solutions

Comment: and as per your error log . you have id column in both tables and it is causing this error . try to give proper alias name for the particular table

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande you say right, but how can I do that?

Comment: Be explicit about where each column comes from, e.g. `OVER ( ORDER BY a.Id DESC )`. It makes it clearer to the reader and, in cases like this, makes it unambiguous to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is where you are causing error. try to give alias to your row number like this instead of `[ID]` give `[a.Id]`

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
                    (  
                          ORDER BY [a.Id] DESC  
                    )AS RowNumber
```

and further you can join another table using `ON` keyword stated by another answer here by adesc

so the whole query will go like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [a.Id] DESC )AS RowNumber ,
a.Id ,
a.ad_title ,
a.ad_state ,
a.ad_city ,
a.ad_brief ,
a.ad_pic 
INTO #Results 
FROM [tbl_ads] a 
join tbl_state b 
ON a.ad_city=b.Id
```

Comment: ERROR:Invalid column name 'a.Id'.

Comment: @Mike you want Id from table `tbl_ads` right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a "JOIN tbl_state ON" to the query.

Comment: but when I use this it give an error: `code         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
                (  
                      ORDER BY [Id] DESC  
                )AS RowNumber  
          ,a.Id  
           ,a.ad_title
     ,a.ad_state
     ,a.ad_city
    ,a.ad_brief  
          ,a.ad_pic    
        INTO #Results  
        FROM [tbl_ads] a join tbl_state b ON a.ad_city=b.Id `  ERROR: Ambiguous column name 'Id'.

Comment: Instead of b.Id, write : tbl_state.Id

Comment: ERROR: The multi-part identifier "tbl_state.Id" could not be bound.